# Liquibase: MEDIUMTEXT character set not being set

Tags: java, mysql, liquibase, amazon-aurora

I have liquibase change set for a mysql aurora db:

```
<changeSet author="xxxxxx" id="1553175489296-3">
    <createTable tableName="event">
        <column name="id" type="VARCHAR(64)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="created" type="datetime">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="created_by" type="VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"/>
        <column name="description" type="MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"/>
        <column name="external_service_config" type="MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"/>
        <column name="language" type="VARCHAR(3) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

The `VARCHAR(*)` field type encoding is set correctly, but `MEDIUMTEXT` remains the default database one.

Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I cannot go with

```
<modifySql dbms="mysql">
            <append value="ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"/>
</modifySql>
```

Since that one sets encoding for the whole table and I cannot do that as I have keys that are longer than 787 bytes. So column specific encodings are the only way for me.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this works pretty well. You must put it after `</createTable>` tag if you have any `MEDIUMTEXT` fields in that table.

```
<modifySql dbms="mysql">
            <replace replace="MEDIUMTEXT"
                     with="MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"/>
</modifySql>
```